# Python: urlparse confuses URL with bracket in the password for IPv6

Tags: python, ftp, ipv6, ipv4, urlparse

Python 2.7 (although this manifested itself in Python 3 as well)

We have a database full of URLs of the form:

`ftp://username1:password1@www.google.com/ 
ftp://username2:password2@www.google.com/`
etc.

Should the passwords be encrypted and stored in a separate column? Probably.

One of our users recently changed the password of the batch job account to include a bracket. This is crashing our script whenever it tries to urlparse it. Urlparse interprets it as a malformed IPv6 address. I think this is a failure of urlparse to not respect the @ symbol, but I could be wrong.

Anyway we have a legacy system that was re-activated to handle this job, but it's not ideal. Any thoughts on how to handle this (other than change the password)? Are there any alternatives to urlparse?

The Python3 equiv has the same issue. I will go through the pain of upgrading to Python3 if I knew it would fix it.

Comment: can you escape the bracket(`\[` (probably not))? or urlencode it(`%5b`)?

Comment: also who uses ftp? what kind of kookiness is this anyway plaintext passwords and ftp servers to boot

Comment: Enterprises still use whitelisted FTP/SFTP believe it or not for regular data transfer. And no, I tried URL encoding and escaping: no joy.

Comment: sftp yes ... but ftp on an accessible network is crazyness.... very very bad form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In summary: Python behaves correctly. Your understanding of what should be the correct behavior is instead wrong.

---

The syntax of a URI is defined in [RFC 4986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). The relevant part about `userinfo`  (i.e. `username` or `username:password`) says clearly that no plain '[' is allowed inside the `userinfo`:

```
authority     = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
userinfo      = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )

pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

As can be seen a '[' is neither part of `unreserved` nor of `sub-delims`. This means you have to encode this character with percent encoding, i.e. `%5B`.

Comment: Hm OK I tried URL encode but I think it capture too much. I will try only encoding the bracket to see if this works. Thanks for your input; will report back on Monday.